# Send message directly to user

Tags: c#, netty

I wish to send messages to a client directly via their IP address. I am currently only able to send messages when `ChannelRead0` is called in the handler and grabbing the context from there:

```
protected override void ChannelRead0(IChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet) {

   ctx.WriteAsync(new DatagramPacket(buffer, packet.Sender));

}
```

My bootstrapper:

```
var bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap
  .Group(group)
  .Channel<SocketDatagramChannel>()
  .Option(ChannelOption.SoBroadcast, true)
  .Handler(new LoggingHandler("SRV-LSTN"))
  .Handler(new ActionChannelInitializer<IChannel>(channel =>  {

      channel.Pipeline.AddLast("UDPServer", new protocols.UDP());

  }));


IChannel boundChannel = await bootstrap.BindAsync(8888);
```

I want to be able to send messages from outside this function as well. Is there any way in which I can send a client a message from outside this function / class? I have tried writing to `boundChannel` however it appears that it doesn't wave a `.write` or `.writeAsync` function.

I am using the DotNetty library (https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty) which was ported from Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `IChannel` has an [`WriteAndFlushAsync`](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty/blob/dev/src/DotNetty.Transport/Channels/IChannel.cs#L68) method that you can use to write a message, this is similair to the `writeAndFlush` method in the Java version of Netty.

Comment: Thanks for the help there. I think I was suffering from tunnel vision.